# React Native button

Tags: reactjs, button, native

есть кнопка

```
<Button
  title="Press me"
  onPress={() => Alert.alert('Hello')}
/>
```

как мне заменить 'Hello' на переход по ссылке (google.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'

<Button
  title="Press me"
  onPress={() => Linking.openURL(url)}
/>
```

Comment: спасибо  за помощь